# Помогите с регулярными

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Прошу Вашей помощи.

Есть текст:

> По происхождению натуральный мёд может быть цветочный и [[Падевый мёд|падевый]].
> Цветочный и [[падевый мёд]]
> Цветочный мёд производится пчёлами в процессе сбора и переработки [[Нектар (сахаристый сок)|нектара]], выделяемого [[нектарник]]ами растений как цветковыми, так и внецветковыми.
> [[Падевый мёд]] пчёлы вырабатывают, собирая [[Падь (пчеловодство)|падь]] (сладкие выделения [[тля|тли]] и некоторых других насекомых) и медвяную росу с листьев или стеблей растений. Падевый мёд токсичен для пчёл, поэтому его не оставляют в ульях на период зимовки пчёл.
> Виды цветочного мёда

Я хочу выбрать в нем все, что в квадратных скобках, например: [[падевый мёд]] и [[нектарник]]

Отдельной регуляркой я хочу выбрать вхождения, вроде этих: [[тля|тли]] и  [[Падь (пчеловодство)|падь]] (т.е. с вертикальной чертой), но так, чтобы я смог переделать это в preg_replace, взяв отдельно строку до черты и после черты.

Я пробовал в первом случае делать так: `\[\[[а-я]+\]\]`
Но это не работает во вхождениях с пробелами. Пытаюсь добавить пробел: `\[\[[а-я, ]+\]\]` или так `\[\[[а-я]+\s\]\]` - не работает вообще.
Думаю, если я пойму принцип первой регулярки, вторую сделать не составит труда. Однако,
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://ideone.com/lcdLxo)**

```
# Если эти паттерны будут использоваться в preg_replace,
# то выражения между знаками @ нужно обернуть в скобки
$patterns = array(
    'only_one_variant' => '@\[\[[^\]\|]++\]\]@',
    'two_and_more_variants' => '@\[\[[^\]\|]++(?:\|[^\]\|]++)+\]\]@',
);

# Разберем сначала паттерн @\[\[[^\]\|]++\]\]@
# @ обозначает начало и конец паттерна
# \[\[ равносильно [[
# \]\] равносильно ]]
# [^\]\|]++ - искать как можно более длинную последовательность символов без ] и |

# Разберем теперь паттерн @\[\[[^\]\|]++(?:\|[^\]\|]++)+\]\]@
# Первую часть уже разобрали, смотри выше. А об этой (?:\|[^\]\|]++)+ подробнее ниже:
# ?: указывает на то, что содержимое скобок запоминать не надо. Это просто группировка
# \| равносильно |
# [^\]\|]++ - искать как можно более длинную последовательность символов без ] и |
# + - искать повторения группы в скобках от 1 до бесконечности раз

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
unset($matches);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[падевый мёд]]
            [1] => [[нектарник]]
            [2] => [[Падевый мёд]]
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[Падевый мёд|падевый|падевый]]
            [1] => [[Нектар (сахаристый сок)|нектара]]
            [2] => [[Падь (пчеловодство)|падь]]
            [3] => [[тля|тли]]
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[\[[а-яёА-Я \(\)\|]+\]\]/U

string(23) "[[Падевый мёд|падевый]]"
[1]=>
string(15) "[[падевый мёд]]"
[2]=>
string(35) "[[Нектар (сахаристый сок)|нектара]]"
[3]=>
string(13) "[[нектарник]]"
[4]=>
string(15) "[[Падевый мёд]]"
[5]=>
string(28) "[[Падь (пчеловодство)|падь]]"
[6]=>
string(11) "[[тля|тли]]"
```

Comment: @lampa, совпадения с одним вариантом внутри скобок и с несколькими вариантами внутри скобок нужно разнести по разным регулярками по условиям задачи

Comment: @VenZell да можно сразу сделать один агрегатор:

    if(strpos($variable, "|")) { // выражение

    }
    else { // слово

    }

Answer (score 0):

[а-я]+\s - таким выражением вы находите все слова в конце которых есть пробел. Если пробела нету ничего не найдется.

во первых пробел может быть а может и не быть, во вторых слов может быть одно или несколько, поэтому так - ([а-я]+\s?)+

Еще в вашем тексте есть слова с большой буквы, которые вы тоже не берете, учтите и это